# Math formalisation of simple programming procedures

Tags: proof-writing, education, learning

I would like to translate some simple programming operation in mathematical equation.

I am very new to formalisation.

I would like to describe these 2 sequences formally. I am not really sure how to start. This is what I came up with :

---

[image]

Let $\varpi$ be a dummy vector such as

$\varpi_{t}=
\begin{cases}
1      & \quad \text{if Done}  \\
0  & \quad \text{if Not Done} \\
\end{cases}$

Let $A$ and $B$ represent two sequences of $\varpi$ both belonging to a related unit $c$. Time (or the position along the sequence) is represented by $t$ with $t = (1, 2, t,\dots, t_{-1}, T = 10)$, where $T$ is the sequence length or the last position of the sequence.

$\xi_{c}$ represents the matched $\varpi_{t}$ for both sequences.

$\xi_{c} = 
\begin{cases}
1      & \quad \text{if } A\varpi_{t} = B\varpi_{t} \\
0  & \quad \text{if } A\varpi_{t} \neq B\varpi_{t}\\
\end{cases}$

$\vartheta_{c}$ represents the combined length of $\varpi_{t}$ sequences.

$\vartheta_{c} = 
\begin{cases}
1      & \quad \text{if } A\varpi_{t} |  B\varpi_{t} \\
0  & \quad \text{Other}\\
\end{cases}$

Finally, $o_{c}$ is the inverse of $\xi_{c}$. (How can I write this simply?)

---

I wonder how to correctly write operation such as `OR` `|` and also `AND` `&`. 
Is it good practice to do that or not ?

$ \xi_{c} = 
\begin{cases}
1      & \quad \text{if } A\varpi_{t} = B\varpi_{t} \\
0  & \quad \text{if } A\varpi_{t} \neq B\varpi_{t}\\
\end{cases}
$

Any correction or suggestion ?

Comment: You can write $o_c = 1-\xi _c$

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando no this will gives wrong results because $\xi$ is conditioned on $\varpi$